# Which is faster Sum Array Rows or Sum Array Cols for x86_64?

Tags: c, arrays, x86-64

So there's two way to calculate 2 dimensional array by iterating the first dimension or the second dimension first. But, which one is faster to get the sum of a 2 dimensional array for the x86_64 machine architecture?

This is the C code for the sum array rows

```
int sum_array_rows(double a[16][16]){
    int i, j;
    double sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 16; j++)
            sum += a[i][j];
    return sum;
}
```

and this is the sum array cols

```
int sum_array_cols(double a[16][16]){
    int i, j;
    double sum = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < 16; j++)
        for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            sum += a[i][j];
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Run them and find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complexity of both functions are identical.

However, the CPU has faster access to adjacent cells as it load a memory page in its cache (Spectre and Meltdown attacks are based on this optimization).

The array is 16 rows of 16 columns, which in memory is something like

```
d[0][0]|d[0][1]|...|d[0][15]|d[1][0] ...
```

So, theoretically the first one should be faster. But considering the array itself is quite small (in memory), the difference, if any, should be minimal.